# Why does Typescript Awaited turns the type into a function instead of the unwrapped type in a promise?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, typescript-typings

I'm trying to get the actual return type of a function which returns a promise. Here's what I did:

```
const myFunction = async (): Promise<number> => {
  return 123;
}

type R = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof myFunction>>;
const result: R = 123; // TS error: Initializer type number is not assignable to variable type R
```

However, this doesn't work for very weird reasons. I'm expecting `R` to be a number. But it seems like Typescript thinks that the type `R` is not number but the following type:

```
(value: number) => (PromiseLike<TResult1> | TResult1) extends ((value: infer V, ...args: infer _) => any) ? Awaited<V> : never
```

In my IDE, it's showing this:

[image]

[image]

This is puzzling because how did `Awaited` turn the type of `R` into a strange looking function that I didn't declare anywhere.

I'm using Typescript 5.0.4. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Not reproducible on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGIFczCgS3DAvDAQwgXRgAoBKALhgAUAnEOTCAUwB4wU4AjV+gHx4hAbwBQMGPVZQU9MDACMAJgDMAbjEBfMWKgIADqxgAlPDACCAdwKYorACbsTMuWAAqhjvqMgAZvDIaBjYYAICmqCQsNIQKAA2UDRm+CoaMAD0GTDuAMow-Iz0NACSYHaYBPGYAF78MD7GXLz1LDBgILBEEJgA5mAEPPHGUCAwAG4E9JVDI16mQA)

Comment: What IDE is this specifically? IntelliJ? WebStorm? And what version/operating system?

Comment: I just installed WebStorm and it works

Comment: @Samathingamajig I'm using IntelliJ which is pretty much Webstorm. I'm aware that it works in TS Playground which makes it super strange because I don't understand why it doesn't work when parsed by the same version of TS in IntelliJ.

Comment: But, by looking at how the type was turned into a function, does it give any clue what could have resulted in that? It seems very strange that it converted the type to a function that has a `value` parameter and some `PromiseLike` returns.

Comment: can't reproduce in 2023.1; what IDE version do you use? As a workaround, please change the typescript version to `Bundled` in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript** and make sure that the language service is enabled.

Comment: @lena Thanks! Strangely, when I change to the typescript version to the `Bundled` one, which is at TS v4 instead of v5, the error goes away. This is still funny because the typescript I have installed to my project in my `package.json` is v5 and will be compiled in v5. Yet, I have to use v4 in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this type instead `Awaited`:

```
type AwaitedFix<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? AwaitedFix<U> : T
```

That seems to be an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-61633/vue-typescript-Awaited-problem) with Webstorm while using some external packages in your project (`"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.37.1"` in case described)